# Long cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

I did almost everything to solve the annoying issue with "Long cannot be dereferenced", but anything worked out. Thus, can anyone please, help me? The problem is when I check if program timed out in `if(System.currentTimeMillis().longValue()==finish)`, the comparison is not working.

```
public void play() 
    {            
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long finish = begin + 10*1000; 

        while (found<3 && System.currentTimeMillis() < finish) {
            Command command = parser.getCommand();
            processCommand(command);
        }
        if(System.currentTimeMillis().longValue()==finish){
            if(found==1){System.out.println("Time is out. You found "+found+" item.");}
            else if(found>1 && found<3){System.out.println("Time is out. You found "+found+" items.");}}
        else{
            if(found==1){System.out.println("Thank you for playing. You found "+found+" item.");}
            else if(found>1 && found<3){System.out.println("Thank you for playing. You found "+found+" items.");}
            else{System.out.println("Thank you for playing.  Good bye.");}
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a difference between `Long`, which is a class, and thus has methods, and `long`, which is a primitive type, and thus doesn't have methods. System.currentTimeMillis() returns a long, not a Long. You're doing he right thing in the while loop, but not in the if. So you already have the solution in your code.

Comment: The problem in my code is that time limit comparison is not working. And that is the reason to post it here

Comment: You also seem to think that System.currentTimeMillis(), when called repeatedly, will give you each and every millisecond. It won't. Calling it itself takes time, and so does what you have inside your while loop. And the precision of the clock is often around 10 milliseconds.

Comment: In this case, can you please give me a working solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a primitive `long` not a object `Long`.
So you cannot invoke the `longValue()` method or any method on it as primitive cannot be the object of method invocations.

Besides, it is useless to invoke `longValue()` as System.currentTimeMillis() returns already a long value.

This is better :

```
    if(System.currentTimeMillis()==finish){
```

But in fact this condition :  `if(System.currentTimeMillis()==finish)` could not be `true` even if  `System.currentTimeMillis() == finish` in the `while` statement :

```
    while (found<3 && System.currentTimeMillis() < finish) {
        Command command = parser.getCommand();
        processCommand(command);
    }
```

Because between the end of the while statement and the condition evaluation :

`if(System.currentTimeMillis() == finish)`,  the time goes on elapsing.

So you should rather use :

```
 if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= finish){
```

Comment: Thus, what is the solution? How to make the time limit comparison work?

Comment: I have updated to explain the problem beyond the compilation error

Comment: Perfect! It worked smoothly. And it is really great idea with a simple solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome :) Suitable solutions are often very simple :)